# Как привязать координаты к изменяемому окну

Tags: python

Дано: есть окно и есть скрипт, который берет данные с помощью создания скриншотов в заданных координатах, но если окно сдвинуть или изменить размер окна, все ломается. Для скрипта использую pyautogui. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как такую проблему можно решить. Спасибо

Comment: Через операционную систему узнавать координаты окна, для винды это winapi

Comment: А как это поможет? Скрипт делает много скриншотов в разных частях окна, и если окно изменит положение, мы получим координаты нового окна, но координаты скриншотов в скрипте никак от этого не поменяются

Comment: Зная координаты окна и его размер, можно сдвигать координаты области скриншота